# Create and add dynamic List in WebApi 2.0

Tags: c#, list

currently I'm using DTO's and writing my Get Method, which looks like this:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetOrder() {
            var order = from x in db.Order
                        select new OrderDTO {
                            OrderId = x.OrderId,
                            orderStatusCode = x.orderStatusCode,
                            OrderProducts = new List<OrderProductDTO> {
                                new OrderProductDTO {
                                   OrderId = x.OrderProducts.Select(y => y.OrderId)
                                }
                            },
                            purchaseDate = x.purchaseDate,
                            quantityOrder = x.quantityOrder,
                            totalOrderPrice = x.totalOrderPrice,
                            User = new UserDTO {
                                UserId = x.UserId,
                                username = x.User.username,
                                userInfo = new UserInfoDTO {
                                    adress = x.User.UserInfo.adress,
                                    city = x.User.UserInfo.city,
                                    country= x.User.UserInfo.country,
                                    zip  = x.User.UserInfo.zip
                                }
                            }

                        };
            return Ok(order);
        }
```

The problem I have is how can I initialize my list dynamically, the error i get is:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'int'.

I get why the problem occurs but dunno how to fix it, thanks. By the way `OrdeProducts` is a `List`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
new OrderProductDTO {
   OrderId = x.OrderProducts.Select(y => y.OrderId)
}
```

`.Select` is returning `IEnumerable<int>`. You are trying to assign it to an `int`.

Instead of enumeration, get just one `int`:

```
new OrderProductDTO {
   OrderId = x.OrderProducts.Select(y => y.OrderId).FirstOrDefault()
}
```